# Как лучше взаимодействовать с бд в wpf приложении?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, entity-framework

Занимаюсь разработкой wpf приложения. Попробовала доставать данные из существующей базы данных двумя способами: 
1) через модель, созданную с помощью EF
2) с помощью прямого обращения к бд, используя SqlConnection, SqlCommand и т.п.
Оба способа освоила и все работает

А что лучше использовать?
И от чего отталкиваться в этом выборе?

Answer (score 3):

EF дает вам преимущества ORM - автоматический маппинг сущностей и их связей на сишарповые классы и изменения в них - обратно в базу.

Голый ADO.NET быстрее.

Всё.